# Moving to the next line in sheet with excel macro for as400

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange

I have a very basic knowledge of VBA and I am trying to copy data from an excel file into AS400. I searched this website and found the code I altered and this works fine, but it always stops after it has finished the first row in the spreadsheet. What code do I need to add so it will jump to the 2nd, 3rd. ... row after the macro has finished one.

Thanks a lot for your help.

I have already tried searching it on this website and online.

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)
Dim excel
Dim row
Dim inputFilename 

inputFilename = "C:\testfile.xlsx"

Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(inputFilename)
excel.visible = true 'If you want to

row = 2 'Start at row 2 of your excel sheet

'Loop until AS400 has blocked input (error in most cases) or there are no values in column A of excel sheet left
while autECLSession.autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 AND excel.Cells(row,2).Value <> "" 

   '### YOUR MACRO STARTS HERE
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys excel.Cells(row,2).Value 'Value of column B / current row from excel sheet
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf2]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys excel.Cells(row,3).Value 'Value of column C / current row from excel sheet
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf2]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys excel.Cells(row,4).Value 'Value of column D / current row from excel sheet
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf2]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys excel.Cells(row,5).Value 'Value of column E / current row from excel sheet
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf2]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf13]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "0"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys excel.Cells(row,6).Value 'Value of column F / current row from excel sheet
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf10]"




   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[eraseeof]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "100"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf2]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "4"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[attn]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"


   ' ...

   '### YOUR MACRO ENDS HERE

   row = row + 1
wend

excel.Quit
Set excel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the code instantiates `row` statically:

```
row = 2 'Start at row 2 of your excel sheet
```

and uses it in the `While`loop:

```
while autECLSession.autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 AND excel.Cells(row,2).Value <> ""
```

What is needed is to "loop" through the rows, which can be done using `For...Next` (you'll wnat to read up on that). You don't tell us how many rows, or what the conditions are to stop, but something like the following code snippet.

This instantiates and assigns objects for the Worksheet, then the Range containing the data. It assumes the first worksheet in the workbook (because according to the code in the question that's correct) and the `UsedRange` on that worksheet. `UsedRange` is the contiguous block of cells containing content on the worksheet.

```
'Declare a Worksheet object and set it to the correct Sheet in the workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
'Declare the Range that contains the rows
Dim theRange as Range
Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set theRange = ws.UsedRange

For Each row in theRange.Rows
  while autECLSession.autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 AND theRange.Cells(row,2).Value <> "" 
  'More code here
Next
```